# Count and groupby in Python

Tags: python, count, group-by

I have created the following code which counts the amount of times a person (by their login_id) has logged into a program over a period of a year.

```
data1.query("'2015-12-01' <= login_date <= '2016-12-01'").groupby(['employer_key','account_id']).size().reset_index().groupby(['employer_key','account_id'])[[0]].count()
```

The output looks something like this:

```
employer_key   account_id  # times logged in
 Apple            X1             1
 Google           Y5             2
 Facebook         X3             4
 Apple            X2             2
 Facebook         Y2             1
```

I would like to count the number of account_ids for each separate employer_key, so that I can determine how many accounts logged in for each individual employer over a period of a year.

The output would hopefully look something like this:

```
employer_key   user_logins
 Apple            2             
 Google           1             
 Facebook         2
```

Comment: How many *unique* accounts?

Comment: In my actual data set I have thousands.

Comment: No, my question is if you want to count *unique* users per employer. I think your data may already have only unique `account_id` in that column, so it may be a moot point.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, all the account_ids are unique.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should work:

```
data.groupby(['employer_key','account_id']).count().\
             unstack().sum(axis=1).astype(int)
#employer_key
#Apple       2
#Facebook    2
#Google      1
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: How is my above code factored into the code you provided? When I run your code, it returns me data for all dates, not for my specified one year period. I am not sure how to integrate the one year period into your code. Thanks!

Comment: My answer is applicable to the output of your code, as shown in your first output block.

Comment: What specific part linking the two codes? Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it.